# What is this part's name and what should I put in there?

Tags: antenna, surface-mount

I just bought one of these SMD antennas and I'm confused how I should use it or where I should put it. It has no datasheet just some pictures from [Aliexpress](https://nl.aliexpress.com/item/1005003099434386.html?gatewayAdapt=glo2nld). In this picture it says I should use two 0 ohm resistors and a "NC" shunt?

Can someone please tell me about shunt and what is NC in this picture?

[image]

Comment: Those pads are for an attenuator, three resistors in a T arrangement to lower a signal level while maintaining the same impedance, or matching one impedance to another. If not needed you simply short out the series connections while leaving the shunt connection out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"NC" = not connected, i.e., don't populate this part.